# Android - GPS Location Update - Need to Cancel TimerTask

Tags: android, gps, timeout, timertask

What I'm trying to do:

1) Update a user's location info every x minutes

2) Use a timer and TimerTask to call a web service which records the latest location info

What's happening:

1) The TimerTask is created

2) If the user's phone is hibernating/sleeping, the call to the web service doesn't work

3) The TimerTask appears to be getting stored in a queue

4) When the user's phone wakes up, all of the queued TimerTasks execute immediately, resulting in multiple unwanted location updates against the web service

Here's the code snippet:

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
@Override
public void run() {

    try
    {
        //validate that the device has an active & working connection
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        //validate the the device network provider is enabled
        if ((eview_locationManagerwifi
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) && (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED))
        {
                UpdateSubscriberLocation(); // call the web service to report location data                                                 
        }
        else
        {
            this.cancel();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {


    }
```

The network connectivity and provider-is-enabled checks are apparently both returning with "true," because the TimerTask doesn't get canceled, it just gets queued until the user's phone wakes up.

How can I cancel the TimerTask if a certain period of time has elapsed without a response from the web service? I wasn't able to find a sort of "setTimeout" method on the TimerTask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the TimerTask, use LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates().  This doesn't add up like the TimerTask and it simplifies the code quite a bit.  You also get the added benefit of avoiding work if the users location does not change.

Comment: If I can find a way around using the TimerTask, that's great - I'm using it because I need this code to fire at regular intervals (user-determined). I like the idea of not processing anything if the user location doesn't change, but how can I be sure that the code will run at the regularly-scheduled intervals without using the Timer/TimerTask combination?

Comment: Wait, I think I might have discovered the answer, actually. The requestLocationUpdates() call includes a regular time interval, doesn't it? So if I make a call to this method when the app starts up, it should continue to fire every x milliseconds, correct?

Comment: The time interval for requestLocationUpdates is just a hint for the location manager. You might get fewer or more locations and if the device hibernates you won't get any further updates!

Comment: If the device hibernates, are you saying that I won't get any more location updates after that point, or will they resume once the device wakes up?

Comment: Stefan is correct about the time interval being a hint (of sorts).  I take advantage of the minDistance and minTime parameters to limit the amount of data to record in my app.  If the user is not moving, then there is no reason to update things.  As far as I know, LocationManager includes a PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, so it will keep the CPU going and get you updates as you need them.

Comment: @jsmith: The LocationManager will not send location updates if the device hibernates. You need to manage the WakeLock yourself.

Comment: Stefan is correct and disclosed a bug in my software.  LocationManager uses the wake lock to prevent hibernation while it's sending an update.  But once it hibernates, it does not send updates.  JMax2012: If you need to log even during hibernation, then do as Stefan suggested and manage a WakeLock in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you need fast updates use a WakeLock to prevent the devices shutting off the CPU. See here for details: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

If you do not need fast updates (lets say every other minute use the AlarmManager. If the alarm is fired request a location update, send your data and set the next alarm: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: Just to clarify the OP and the code snippet there: the update task should fire based on a user-defined setting, usually every 15 minutes or every 30 minutes, based on what the user chooses in their preference settings.

Comment: The LocationManagerService does include a PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, so I don't you need to include that in your app.